# Word to describe action of an audio indicator

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Wondering if there is a good word to fit the following:

**Indicate** is to **lamp** (or LED, light, globe, display)
or
**Prickle** is to **electrical shock** (or wire brush)
or
**Buzz** is to **vibrator**
as
**_____** is to **beeper** (or speaker, bell, buzzer)

I read an instruction that mentioned an indicator but they were referring to a speaker and not a light and it felt clumsy.

I am wondering if there is a word like indicator, which has a feeling of visual sense, that would be more appropriate for auditory signalling.

**EDIT:**
Fixed word form,  Added some more senses that may help direct enquiry.

```
The apparatus will indicate the ready state.
```

I am hoping that to replace the word **indicate** with something else in an instruction manual that would let the reader presume the **ready state signal** is from an audio source rather than a light source.  The word **sound** seems old fashioned and would have matched OK with bells and buzzers of yesteryear that were often collectively referred to as sounders but would not make as much sense in the contemporary world of ear-buds, mini speakers and tiny buzzers and beepers on modern electronics.  The word **signal** seems like a possible alternative to **indicate** but it does not strongly suggest audio, it could be referring to a flag that pops up so not ideal either.

Comment: 'flash' and 'beep', unless I'm not understanding properly.

Comment: When a lamp is lit, it does not need an indicator light to show it's on, but other things like a speaker do.

Comment: In a technical setting, annunciate/[annunciator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annunciator)/annunciation/annunciatory work, but I wouldn't use it in instructions written using a basic vocabulary

Comment: @marcellothearcane your term __beep__ may turn out to be the best solution even if the sound is a __buzz__ or a __ding__ in practice, it is more specific but still suitably descriptive.

Comment: @KalleMP what is the specific sound your device makes? A chirp?

Comment: @PV22  You have located the root of my problem.  I expect it will be a _click_ in this case as it relates to a _Geiger counter_ but it could be _chirps_ or _beeps_ or whatever.  I was hoping for a delightful sound agnostic verb like __sound__ that is more contemporary. For the ears instead of eye.

Answer (score 2):

> **Sound**
>   /verb (used with object),  (used without object)
>
> 1. to cause to make or emit a sound:
>      *to sound a bell.*
> 2. to announce, order, or direct by or as by a sound: *The bugle sounded retreat.*
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sound)

Comment: I agree that this may be the correct word instead of indicate but it does not have a good feel in the example type sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The speaker or beeper will **sound** when activated.

From **[MW](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sound)**:

> **sound** verb (NOISE)
>
> [ I or T ] **to make a noise:**
>
> *If the alarm sounds, leave the building immediately.*
>
> *It sounds like a bird.*
>
> *He sounds (= speaks) just like someone I used to work with.*
>
> *Sounding the car's horn, she drove at high speed through the crowded streets.*
>
> ---
>
> **sound the alarm**
>   ​>
>
> **to cause a noise to be made or say or shout a message to warn people about something:**
>
> *Quick, sound the alarm - there's a fire in the machine room!*

[image]

Comment: I agree that this may be the correct word instead of indicate but it does not have a good feel in the example type sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> **Signal**
> [sig-nl]
>
> /noun
>
> 1. anything that serves to indicate, warn, direct, command, or the like, as a light, a gesture, an act, etc.
>
> /verb (used with object)
>
> 2. to communicate or make known by a signal.

IMOO the word **signal** has a better "ring" to it, compared to indicate.

Comment: I agree that _signal_ is a good word that removes the visual assumption but does not preclude it.  However it does not favour the audio aspect in any way.  I think it is one step better than _indicate_ in most cases but may not be appropriate in this instance when I am hoping to emphasize the audio nature of the signalling.

Answer (score 1):

**Chime:** to put, bring, indicate, announce, etc.

A few other definitions from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chime) are shown below.

[image]

In the simplest case, you could say: "The device will chime when ready."

However, I personally think a little more detail would make the instructions more clear for the end user. Indicating how many times the device will chime, and what the device will do next seems like a great way to round out the sentence. As an example: "The device will chime twice when it is ready to ___"

Comment: Now that I think about it, "ring" could also work. I think chime is a bit better in context though.

Comment: Dsel I would like it to be simple and descriptive too. I am thinking of editing a wikipedia page and am stumped for a tidy word that would describe the audio aspect of the signal instead of the word indicate that always makes me think of an optical signal.  I cannot be sure of what sound a generic device will make. If I was writing instructions for a specific device I would do like you suggest and be more specific.

Comment: The 'Chime' sound would be appropriate for Apple products that have been known to make a chime on wake up.  However my goal here was to find a word that is agnostic of the type of sound but still weigh heavily on the side of a sound indication/signal rather than a visual indication/signal.

Answer (score 1):

> **Resonate**[ rez-uh-neyt ]
>
> verb (used without object), res·o·nat·ed, res·o·nat·ing.
>
> 1) to resound.
>
> 2) to act as a resonator; exhibit resonance.
>
> 3) Electronics. to reinforce oscillations because the natural frequency of the device is the same as the frequency of the source.
>
> 4) to amplify vocal sound by the sympathetic vibration of air in certain cavities and bony structures.
>
> verb (used with object), res·o·nat·ed, res·o·nat·ing.
>
> 5) to cause to resound.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/resonate)

MOO: Last one... does not have any association with any other indication other than sound... Less “archaic sounding” than Resound.

If not... slap that indicator into IoT and have it text a message to your smart phone.

Comment: I like the way you think and it does indeed conjure up sound (and all sorts of other vibrations electrical and mechanical) but it is not something I would expect to see in a user guide to prepare me to hear a wake-up or activity sound.  It is what I would expect from a massager attached to a paint tin.

Answer (score 0):

Speaker or buzzer would fit.  Claxton or alarm would also work.

Comment: Thank you. The word __alarm__ is correct from the audio aspect but carries too much urgency for normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

> **Resound** [ri-zound]
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> 1) to echo or ring with sound, as a place.
>
> 2) to make an echoing sound, or sound loudly, as a metallic object: A gong resounded.
>
> 3) to ring or be echoed, as sounds.
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1) to reecho (a sound).
>
> 2) to give forth or utter loudly.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/resound)

Comment: I think a bit too formal and loud as an auditory instrument activity indication.

Comment: The hunt continues